# Java: how to set default value to annotation with another annotation as its attribute?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an annotation with 3 attributes:

```
public @interface Date {
    int day() default 1;
    int month() default 1;
    int year() default 2000;
}
```

And annotation that uses previous annotation as attribute:

```
public @interface Author {
    String name();
    Date date(); //default value here
}
```

How to set default value for attribute `date`?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a annotations as a field ? The whole idea of annotations is to be meta-data, not data. Could you share the requirements that lead you to this design ?

Comment: Can't you just do a simple `Date date() default @Date();` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this by providing a default annotaion...

For example:

```
public @interface Author {
    String name();
    Date date() default @Date(year=2014);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think about such variant.

Comment: this is flawless Balder!